# NSURLRequest, NSURLConnection version infomation

Tags: iphone, cocoa, asynchronous, loader

I'm implementing background fetching similar to [this example](http://www.geekygoodness.com/2009/09/13/a-simple-cocoa-asynchronous-image-loader-class-to-use-in-your-iphone-app/).  However, I also need to support devices with older iOS versions (3.0 and up).  So, my question is: What versions will support this?

Also, I've been using the technique of attempting the create the object and checking if it is null as a means of insuring backward compatibility.  However, if there is a way of checking the version directly, that would be great also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance I don't see anything in that code that isn't available with ios 3.0. Therefore you should be OK.

NSURLConnection is Available in iOS 2.0 and later

When you build just ensure you set your iOS Deployment Target to 3.0

Comment: I guess I just needed to know what version these were initially available in.  ... First in, so answered.

Answer (score 0):

The above code appears to be 3.0 compatible.  If you do need to know the version of the OS you can call:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]
```

Also, I looked a the example you're using and there appears to be a significant memory leak.  The line:

```
mutData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] retain];
```

Sets the retain count of mutData to 2, which probably means it won't ever get released.

Comment: Thanks about the info, and especially the memory leak.  Totally escaped me.